# Find and count instance of substring within multiple strings using python

Tags: python, regex, string, substring

I have a sql query within python with multiple sub-queries. So the set up is multiple substrings within a larger string. I would like to check for the number of instances of a string within the substrings. A little more involved than what I have seen posted and appreciate the help.

Set up like this -

```
qry = ''' 
with 
qry_1 as ( 
   SELECT ID, 
          NAME
   FROM   ( ... other code...
),
qry_2 as ( 
    SELECT coalesce (table1.ID, table2.ID) as ID,
           NAME
   FROM (...other code...
),
qry_3 as (
     SELECT id.WEATHER AS WEATHER_MORN,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id.SUN
                ORDER BY id.TIME) AS SUN_TIME,
            id.RAIN,
            id.MIST
   FROM (...other code..
)
'''
```

And I'd like to count the instances of `ID` for within `qry_1, qry_2, qry_3`.

Something I think would leverage `re.findall` and then a substring search?

```
re.findall(r'as \( select (.+?) from \(',qry)
```

And then finding and counting instances of `ID` within this? Where the output is 2. But I'm not sure how...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split the CTE queries, and then use `re.findall` on a truncated version of the subquery:

```
qry = ''' 
with 
qry_1 as ( 
  SELECT ID, 
      NAME
  FROM   ( ... other code...
),
qry_2 as ( 
  SELECT coalesce (table1.ID, table2.ID) as ID,
       NAME
FROM (...other code...
),
qry_3 as (
  SELECT WEATHER
FROM (...other code..
)
'''

def get_cols(s):
   [cte_name] = re.findall('^\w+(?=\sas)|(?<=with\s)\w+(?=\sas)', s)
   cols = re.findall('(?<=as\s)[\w\.]+|(?<=SELECT\s)[\w\.]+|(?<=,\s)[\w\.]+', s)
   return [cte_name, cols]

#dictionary with the cte name as the key, and the columns as the values
v = dict(get_cols(re.sub('coalesce\s\(.+\)|[\s\n]+', ' ', i)) for i in re.split('(?<=\)),(?:\s+)*\n', qry))
#filter the dictionary above to only include desired column names
r = {a:k if (k:=[i for i in b if i in {'NAME', 'ID'}]) else None for a, b in v.items()}
```

Output:

```
{'qry_1': ['ID', 'NAME'], 'qry_2': ['ID', 'NAME'], 'qry_3': None}
```

Comment: excellent, this is really helpful! if i wanted to include in the count whether the string contains ```ID``` as well, for example an instance of ```table.ID```, could i do so?

Comment: @paranormaldist please see my recent edit

Comment: this is great! and one additional question if possible, to include ```ID``` or ```NAME``` in the output. ```{'qry_1': 'ID', 'NAME', 'qry_2': 'ID','NAME', 'qry_3': None}```

Comment: @paranormaldist please see my recent

Comment: i do have an instance in my actual complicated case where i have a ```coalesce``` statement ```select coaesce (NAME FROM (...``` which is not being picked up but I can't figure out why...

Comment: i'm a little confused by the regex syntax, but if it was searching everything within ```SELECT``` to ```FROM``` why would I run into issue for this instance? @Ajax1234

Comment: also, how can I parse out what regex is searching between from the syntax? thanks again

Comment: @paranormaldist Regarding your last question, I would use a separate regex for that task. Can you post your full, more complex statement?

Comment: thanks, i have edited ```qry_2```. so ```ID``` will come up more than once in the search, which is ok can also do unique

Comment: if I did want to search everything between ```as (``` and ```from``` - where can i input the ```from``` here? ```w+\sas\s\([\s\w\.,\n]+'```. after this point here ```\s\w\.,\n]+``` I'm a bit lost

Comment: @paranormaldist Thank you for the update with the new `qry` string, please see my recent edit.

Comment: ah i see thank you @Ajax1234, similarly, if i did want to search within ```re.findall('\w+\s(?i)as\s\([\s\w\.,\nX]+', qry)``` and modify to search up until ```from```, how might i do that? I've tried a number of ways - like this ```re.findall('\w+\s(?i)as\s\([\s\w\.,\sFROM\nX]+', qry)``` but that doesn't work

Comment: @paranormaldist Are you trying to extract the raw column selection statement from the query?

Comment: yes trying to extract the raw column values that are being selected. so i thought best approach would be using chosen identifiers - i've edited ```qry_3``` in my post to show a little of the complication