# Python regex multi-line search between strings

Tags: python, regex, string

a question of mine on a previous post  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66478374/find-and-count-instance-of-substring-within-multiple-strings-using-python/66479093?noredirect=1#comment117682184_66479093) has expanded a bit so I'm asking a separate question for those who are familiar with `regex`.

I have a fairly complicated SQL query syntax where I'd like to find all instances of a string between two other strings in python format.

Simple version setup like this -

```
qry = ''' 
with 
qry_1 as ( 
   SELECT ID, 
          NAME
   FROM   ( ... other code...
),
qry_2 as ( 
    SELECT coalesce (table1.ID, table2.ID) as ID,
           NAME
   FROM (...other code...
),
qry_3 as (
     SELECT id.WEATHER AS WEATHER_MORN,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id.SUN
                ORDER BY id.TIME) AS SUN_TIME,
            id.RAIN,
            id.MIST
   FROM (...other code..
)
'''
```

Where I'd like to find text existing between `as (` and `from`. I've tried a number of things that don't quite work.

Something like -

```
re.findall('\w+\s(?i)as\s\(nX(?i)from+', qry)
```

as part of a larger statement here that I had help with -

```
find_params = [re.findall('^\w+|(?:NAME|ID)|(?<=\.)(?:NAME|ID)', i) 
     for i in re.findall('\w+\s(?i)as\s\(nX(?i)from+', qry)]
```

Comment: i'm not sure why both my posts get downvoted for separating out questions that are related but different

Comment: Like this? `\sas\s*\(\s*((?:\n.*)*?)\n\s*FROM\b` https://regex101.com/r/kzC24o/1

Comment: i see that it should work, but it is coming up as empty ```[ ]```

Comment: Did you use multiline? See https://ideone.com/BpGy47

Comment: excellent! thank you, and if I wanted to search within these outputs - something like this? 

```find_params = [re.findall('^\w+|(?:NAME)|(?<=\.)(?:NAME)', i) 
     for i in re.findall(r"^\S+\s(?i)as\s*\(\s*((?:\n.*)*?)\n\s*FROM\b", qry, re.M)]``` 
returns ```[[ ]]```

Comment: I do get a result, see https://ideone.com/Cv28em (I removed the inline flags for case insensitive, I think that is not supported) But note that this pattern `^\w+|(?:NAME|ID)|(?<=\.)(?:NAME|ID)` matches word characters at the start of the string, or NAME or ID and you can remove `(?<=\.)(?:NAME|ID)` as the part before it already matches it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could match from `as` and as least as possible lines until the next FROM and capture what is in between in a capture group.

```
^\S+\sas\s*\(\s*((?:\n.*)*?)\n\s*FROM\b
```

Another option is to match `as` and prevent crossing lines that start with either `as` as the second word (as in the example data) or start with `FROM` using a negative lookahead.

```
^\S+\sas\s*\([^\S\r\n]*((?:\n(?!\S+ as\b|\s*FROM\b).*)*)\n\s*FROM\b
```

**Note** that these patterns are based on the example data, and do not take possible nested structures into account.

The values of the capture group will be returned by [re.findall](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) for which you might do sub processing as in the question.

|  | Regex demo | Python demo |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | https://regex101.com/r/xoRRBi/1 | https://ideone.com/NjmeKO |
| 2 | https://regex101.com/r/OZMH0A/1 | https://ideone.com/29RO51 |